# creating DTD for binary tree

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

I want to create DTD file that checks if the XML file is a binary tree which in it every node has at most 2 sons and every node should have a pointer to the childern if they exits

how can I implement that in XML ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to write binary trees in XML.  Here's one; it assumes that the value at each node is carried in an attribute named 'value'.

```
<!ELEMENT node (node, node?) >
<!ATTLIST node value CDATA #REQUIRED >
```

It's also possible to require that a node either have two children or none (Wikipedia says this is called a full binary tree):

```
<!ELEMENT node (node, node)? >
```

The first DTD but not the second will accept an XML representation of a simple binary tree (from the Wikipedia article on binary trees):

```
<node value="2">
  <node value="7">
    <node value="2"/>
    <node value="6">
      <node value="5"/>
      <node value="11"/>
   </node>
  <node value="5">
    <node value="9">
      <node value="4"/>
    </node>
  </node>
</node>
```

[Oh, yes, one other thing.  You're much more likely to get good responses to questions on Stack Overflow if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem (this is of course difficult if you have no idea where to start).  Not showing your work gives the impression you haven't done any and just want others to do your work for you.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).]